# Probability that one weighted mean of iid random variables is greater than the other

Tags: probability, statistics

I read somewhere that if $X_1,\dots, X_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_m$ are all i.i.d. and admit probability densities w.r.t the Lebesgue measure and we choose weights $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n,\rho_1,\dots,\rho_m$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_i=\sum_{i=1}^m\rho_i=1$, we have:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_iX_i\leq \sum_{i=1}^m\rho_iY_i\right)=1/2.$$
I have tested this numerically and it seems to hold, but I cannot seem to prove it, does someone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: What if $n=m$, $\omega_j=\rho_j$ and all $X_1,...,X_n,Y_1,...,Y_n$ are constant random variables, let's say they're equal $1$ almost surely. Then $\mathbb P( \sum_{i=1}^n \omega_iX_i \le \sum_{i=1}^m \rho_iY_i) = 1$, because both sums are just $1$, so even the equality holds.

Comment: Thanks, I should have specified that the random variables should admit probability densities w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. But even in this case the result seems false indeed, if we have a skewed distribution with $n$ small and $m$ large I think we get a probability different from 0.5 for a skewed distribution.

Comment: If you add assumption $n=m$ and the distribution is with density (or at least continuous CDF) then the result is indeed true by symmetry.

Comment: But couldn't you then take a small amount of the $\omega_i $ large and the $\rho_i $ relatively the same (approx $1/m$) such that we effectively still end up with small $n$ and large $m$ and hence the situation I sketched before? I think it might only hold if we also have that $(\rho_i)_i$ is a permutation of $(\omega_i)_i$

Comment: Yes, I've missed something in my head when thinking about it earlier. I'm not that sure nowthe result holds in the above general case you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the claim is true in general.

**Example 1.**
Let $n=2$, $m=2$, weights $\omega=(0.9, 0.1)$ and $\rho=(0.5, 0.5)$. Let $X_i,Y_j \sim \text{Exp}(1)$. Then simulations suggest that the probability is about $0.539$.

Or another example, because the weighted sums of exponentials are a bit cumbersome to handle analytically:

**Example 2.** Let $F$ be the mixture distribution of 90% uniform over $[0, 0.001]$ and 10% uniform over $[1,10$]. Let $n=1$, $m=20$, $\omega_1=1$, $\rho_j=1/20$ and $X_i,Y_j \sim F$.

Now the left-hand side $X_1$ has 90% chance of being less than $0.001$. But on the right-hand side, there is $1-0.9^{20} \approx 87.8\%$ chance that at least one of the $Y_j$ is greater than 1, so then the RHS is greater than $0.05$. Clearly there is greater than 75% chance that LHS<RHS. Indeed, if you try it out, you get LHS<RHS about 81.8% of the time.

**Note:** If the common distribution of $X_i,Y_j$ is *symmetric*, then it is not difficult to show (by [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions)) that also LHS and RHS have symmetric distributions; also their difference has a symmetric distribution, with mean $0$, so (by continuity) it is negative with probability $1/2$. So in that case the claim holds.

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that with a weight vector of w=(0.1, 0.9), the probability would be <50%? I don't see how that can be true due to symmetry, as there's nothing that distinguishes X1 from X2.

Comment: @Nuclear Hoagie: No, if you reverse the $\omega$ vector, it does not change the distribution of the left hand side. The LHS distribution is different from the RHS distribution, more peaked near the origin, so it has greater probability of being small (although of course LHS and RHS have equal means).

Comment: Thanks Jukka for the detailed answer!